# Power off block devices

Tags: disk-utility, script, utilities

I would like a way to shut down the block devices to do safe removal by turning them off. On Linux there is the UDisks2's `udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdX` command. Is there something similar? Or if you know a library to use to create a script that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

`umount` will unmount a block storage device. Once the device is unmounted, it is safe to remove/unplug it. There doesn't appear to be a `udiskctl` for macos.